# Boostrap 4 - Logo image doesn't expand header

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm using a bootstrap template (https://bootstrapmade.com/demo/TheEvent/) and I'm trying to include my logo in the header. Unfortunately the logo overlaps and doesn't expand the header and I don't understand why. The header should stay fixed on top of the website, just be big enough to give my logo enough space.

I've tried increasing max-height of the image, but that only leads to overlap.

CSS:

```
#header {
    height: 90px;
    padding: 50px 0;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    z-index: 997;
}

#header.header-scrolled,
#header.header-fixed {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.98);
    height: 70px;
    padding: 15px 0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

#header #logo h1 {
     font-size: 36px;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 6px 0;
     line-height: 1;
     font-family: "Calibri", sans-serif;
     font-weight: 700;
     letter-spacing: 3px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
}

#header #logo h1 span {
     color: #eccd1b;
}

#header #logo h1 a,
#header #logo h1 a:hover {
      color: #fff;
} 

#header #logo img {
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
     max-height: 50px;
}

<header id="header">
    <div class="container">

      <div id="logo" class="pull-left">
        <!-- Uncomment below if you prefer to use a text logo -->
        <!-- <h1><a href="#main">Kombucha <span>Summit</span></a></h1>-->
        <a href="#intro" class="scrollto"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="" title=""></a>
      </div>

      <nav id="nav-menu-container">
        <ul class="nav-menu">
          <li class="menu-active"><a href="#intro">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#supporters">Sponsors</a></li>
          <!--<li><a href="#speakers">Speakers</a></li>-->
          <!--<li><a href="#schedule">Schedule</a></li>-->
          <li><a href="#venue">Venue</a></li>
          <!--<li><a href="#hotels">Hotels</a></li>-->
          <!--<li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>-->
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="buy-tickets"><a href="#buy-tickets">Get notified</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav><!-- #nav-menu-container -->
    </div>
  </header><!-- #header -->
```

Would be awesome if someone could help me with this :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding class `img img-fluid` to your header image. This would set the max-width to be 100% and your image would not overflow

```
<img src="img/logo.png" class="img img-fluid" alt="" title="">
```

Comment: do you have a codepen or a demo setup of what exactly is not working?